# MS Runtime required for app to run, how can I include with setup?

Tags: vb.net, deployment, ms-access-2007

My application requires access to be installed on the computer or at least the MS Access runtime.  Is their a way to include that with the application to check for that component/resource or install it if it isn't?

Or would it just be easier to include a link to tell the user where to get the runtime if the error happens?

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and the windows form app is written in VB.net.  I am currently using click once for the deployment.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could include the runtime with an installer. It can be downloaded here...

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=d9ae78d9-9dc6-4b38-9fa6-2c745a175aed&displaylang=en